# React: How to update nested data structures without having to place all the logic related to it in the parent component

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and this is the first time I have to deal with nested objects.
This is part of the state I need to manage:

```
Model
    |
    |__ModelReturn:{ id: 1, name: "XYZ", modelId:1}
    |
    |
    |__ModelReturn:{ id: 2, name: "ABC", modelId:1}
    |
    |
    |__ModelReturn:{ id: 3, name: "PQR", modelId:1}
```

Because I don't want to specify the structure of every object I create, I have a class for almost every object I use in my application.

For example when I add a new ModelReturn I can simply instantiate a new ModelReturn object instead of having to specify the structure of the object I want to create:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  modelReturns: [...prevState.modelReturns, new ModelReturnEntity()]      
}));
```

Up to that point having such classes seemed to be really convenient, until I had to start updating small pieces of the state, in this case ModelReturn.

You see, because I'm used to objects being passed by reference I thought that if I pass in the ModelReturn object to the ModelReturn component as props and assign that object to the component's state then all the changes made to that state will be reflected in the original state, which live in the Model component.

```
class ModelReturn extends Component {
  constructor(props) {   
    super(props);
    this.state = props.modelReturn;    
  }
  //...
}
```

Knowing that props are read-only values, the only solution I've able to come up with is to pass the methods that will update a certain object all the way down to the component responsible for rendering it.

Is there any better way to pass in a piece of state to a component and that all the changes made by this component get reflected in the state hold by the parent component without having to place all this logic in the parent component?

I know I could use Redux, but I'm  trying to avoid it, at least for now until I feel more confident with just React.

BTW, here's an [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/r0zk2LWPW) of what I trying to build. The files relevant to this question are :

/components/models/Model.js

/components/models/ModelReturnList.js

/components/models/ModelReturn.js